# using div [ngStyle] for background-image and am looping it *ngFor, if any of image is missing ,how to show static image on it using angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

```
<div class="bg" 
     onError="this.src='https://www.tibs.org.tw/images/default.jpg';" 
     [ngStyle]="{'background-image':  'url(' + imgss.image + ')'}"
     *ngFor="let imgss of prod.product_images | slice:0:1;">
</div>
```

how to get alternate image if there is no image on it, i have tried using onError but which works only on image tag,but here am using only div.

Comment: Using `src` attribute on a `div` won't work to display an image, and i doubt `onError` is triggered when background image doesn't load (have you tried a console.log?).

Comment: My guess is you need to do `var tmp = new Image(); tmp.onerror = /* mark as dead */; tmp.src = URL;` and use the results of that to change your array elements to the default URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bg" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': (imgss.image) ? 'url(' + imgss.image + ')' : 'url(https://www.tibs.org.tw/images/default.jpg)' }"
        *ngFor="let imgss of prod.product_images | slice:0:1;"></div>
```

Hope this will help you!